# Socket.IO doing DB update connect to room send msg and disconect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Ive seen many posts but still unable to find answer or even if i'm doing this correctly.

So the Client is sending message for specific room that has another person. I make a POST request to Backend.

This one is fake check of DB if the specific user has the room if so then `emit` message to that specific room only.

```
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const ws = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(ws, { cors: { origin: '*', methods: ['GET'] } });

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App Port ${port}`));
ws.listen(8080, () => console.log(`WS Port 8080`));

app.post('/api/user/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const pUserId = req.params.id;
  const qRoomId = req.query.room_id as string;
  const qMsg = req.query.msg;

  const db_checkIfUserHasRoom = () => {
    const DB_getUserRooms: Record<number, number[]> = {
      1: [1, 2],
      2: [3, 4],
    };
    return DB_getUserRooms[Number(pUserId)].includes(Number(qRoomId));
  };

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('connected', `${socket.id}`);
    socket.join(`room-${qRoomId}`);
    io.sockets.in(`room-${qRoomId}`).emit('connectToRoom', `You are in room no. ${qRoomId}`);
  });
});
```

I think i'm doing this correct but i dont understand how to listen on Client for that room or that after the request has finished do i need Backend to disconnect from that room?

Comment: Are you making the request first and then listening for the user to connect? Maybe do the opposite?